# How can I identify and remove redundant code in Perl?

Tags: perl, refactoring

I have a Perl codebase, and there are a lot of redundant functions and they are spread across many files.

Is there a convenient  way to identify those redundant functions in the codebase?
Is there any simple tool that can verify my codebase for this?

Comment: I am not exactly sure about what you mean when you say "redundant". Are you talking about multiple subs that all do the same job? Or about subs that never get called? Or both?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the [B::Xref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?B::Xref) module to generate cross-reference reports.

Answer (score 8):

I've run into this problem myself in the past.  I've slapped together a quick little program that uses PPI to find subroutines.  It normalizes the code a bit (whitespace normalized, comments removed) and reports any duplicates.  Works reasonably well.  PPI does all the heavy lifting.

You could make the normalization a little smarter by normalizing all variable names in each routine to $a, $b, $c and maybe doing something similar for strings.  Depends on how aggressive you want to be.

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use PPI;

my %Seen;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    my $doc = PPI::Document->new($file);
    $doc->prune("PPI::Token::Comment");         # strip comments

    my $subs = $doc->find('PPI::Statement::Sub');
    for my $sub (@$subs) {
        my $code = $sub->block;
        $code =~ s/\s+/ /;                      # normalize whitespace
        next if $code =~ /^{\s*}$/;             # ignore empty routines

        if( $Seen{$code} ) {
            printf "%s in $file is a duplicate of $Seen{$code}\n", $sub->name;
        }
        else {
            $Seen{$code} = sprintf "%s in $file", $sub->name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! But why do you need to ignore empty routines?

Comment: The purpose is not just to find redundant code but to aid in its removal.  It was quickly obvious upon running that reporting empty routines was just clutter.  There's nothing wrong with `sub foo {}`.  When you think about the alternative `*foo = \&DO_NOTHING`, which is about as silly as `my $foo = $EMPTY_STRING`, it should all make sense.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be convenient, but the best tool for this is your brain. Go through all the code and get an understanding of its interrelationships. Try to see the common patterns. Then, refactor!

I've tagged your question with "[refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/refactoring)". You may find some interesting material on this site filed under that subject.

Comment: I like the stock-room style refactor. 1. Check code into git. 2. Make sure you have lots of tests. 3. Rename the module in entirety to something unusuable. 4. Create an empty one. 5. Copy functions back, refactoring them as you go, until tests pass again. 6. After a month of not needing to copy functions from the old module, remove it.

Comment: @Ether: your are right about refactoring...but first i need to locate the functions..
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux you might use `grep` to help you make list all of the functions in your codebase.  You will probably need to do what Ether suggests and really go through the code to understand it if you haven't already.

Here's an over-simplified example:

```
grep -r "sub " codebase/* > function_list
```

You can look for duplicates this way too.  This idea may be less effective if you are using Perl's OOP capability.

It might also be worth mentioning [NaturalDocs](http://naturaldocs.org/), a code documentation tool. This will help you going forward.

Comment: If you're working with Perl, consider using `ack`, a pure-Perl version of `grep` that takes advantage of Perl's more powerful regex support.